# statusText of HttpErrorRespone is empty string in win10

Tags: javascript, angular, xmlhttprequest

My organization uses angular 1.2.16. We are using "loginResult.statusText" to print an error message. But the statusText is empty in Win10 but gives the expected output in Win7(statustext is not empty in win7).

loginResult(in win10) is something like this:

[image: 1]

I need to understand why statusText prints correct msg in win7 but an empty string in win10. Statustext is empty in chrome and edge of win10. But, statusText contains "Unauthorized"(correct string) in firefox win10

I was trying to print error message

Comment: You could use `status` and if you really need it as text parse it to the corresponding text.
`status` is more reliable anyway.

Comment: I know there are many ways to print the error message. But my organisation is particularly asking for the reason why statusText is empty in Win10 chrome and edge.